# New Thinkpad - fan noise after BIOS upgrade

Tags: bios, lenovo-laptop, thinkpad

I received my brand new Thinkpad P73 4 days ago. I installed it directly in Dual-Bool Xubuntu 18. Everything worked nickel (but at that time, I had not yet used Windows).

But today I went to Windows. In the Lenovo Vantage software (installed by default in Windows) I saw that there was a critical update "update the BIOS". So I did this update, and since then I have a big problem: My fan makes noise (and not only a little, which is annoying). Whether I am on Xubuntu or Windows, it always makes noise ... (so the problem does not come from Xubuntu). And I’m sure it’s since this BIOS update…

Have you ever had this kind of problem? Is there Ubuntu reliable software to control its fans?

PS: in my BIOS, it is not possible to manage the fans (I have already looked for).

And after doing research in Google, I have the impression that it is a recurring problem at Lenovo ... In short, I have 14 days of withdrawal, if no solution these next few days ... I request a refund.

Thank you so much.

Comment: We use lots of Lenovo machines at our clients and I have 3 here - two ThinkPads and one ThinkCenter. BIOS updates are routine and do not cause the fan to run at high speed. I strongly suggest you call Lenovo Support since the machine is new.

Comment: @John your solution is correct.  Calling support is the best option.  However, your reason is wrong.  BIOSs get updates typically because the previous version had bugs or security flaws.  And BIOSs can get updated numerous times.  It is entirely possible the latest version of the BIOS update introduced a bug with the fan.

Comment: It is possible, but is back in the 1980's when I saw such a thing happen and never since. On servers, over 20 years ago. Lenovo is very careful about these things. So my reasoning based on Lenovo is correct not wrong

Comment: thank you.
I called support.
they offered to either repair it or replace it. I refused.
I asked for a refund. Goodbye Lenovo ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's non-reproducible because the customer asked for a refund.

Comment: I have experienced the same issue, since I recently updated the bios on my P73 by means of Lenovo Vantage software.